# request for package qcc 3.0 version

Tags: r, install.packages

I´ve trying for days to update "qcc" package to 3.0 version, but it is impossible, I´ve downloaded my R and R Studio (version 4.1.1) again but qcc still has 2.7 version and I need qcc 3.0, please help.
Thanks.

Comment: [At CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=qcc) latest version is 2.7, if you need the latest install it from GitHub:  `remotes::install_github("luca-scr/qcc")`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.